# Using App Fuse to generate CRUD operations directly from database schema

Tags: java, maven-2, maven-3, appfuse

I was told that one can generate CRUD operations directly form the database schema using app fuse. But I was unsuccessful in doing that using it and it look very long without any clue.

One possibility is to create the models and annotate it and create CRUDs and create database tables and also populate them with dummy variables. But is it possible to do it other way round.

I have been following [this tutorial](http://appfuse.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=11141228) provided from App Fuse. Am I doing it wrong or is it possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try using appfuse:gen-model:

http://static.appfuse.org/plugins/appfuse-maven-plugin/gen-model-mojo.html

Note, that AppFuse isn't great at creating relationships between classes, so you might have to do some work after it generates the code. You also might try searching the user mailing list archives:

http://appfuse.547863.n4.nabble.com/AppFuse-User-f547864.html

Comment: is there an automatic way of creating relationships between classes?